How to Change the Initial Perspective of CameraControls?
I've written a React component where I'm trying to change the initial perspective of CameraControls, but I haven't been successful. Does anyone have any ideas?
The code to change the position of the box in the useEffect hook works fine, but the code for CameraControls doesn't work. I don't know why. Do I need to call a method like update or something?
Here's the code for reference.
const cameraControlsRef = useRef<CameraControls>(null!);
const ref = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(cameraControlsRef);
  // if (!cameraControlsRef.current) return;

  // the code is not working
  cameraControlsRef.current.setLookAt(2.68, 1.32, -1.9, 0, 0, 0);

  // the code is working
  ref.current.position.y = 1;
}, []);

return (
  <>
    <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault fov={70} position={[5, 0, 0]} />
    <CameraControls ref={cameraControlsRef} />

    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshNormalMaterial />
    </mesh>
  </>
);


